# Only execute function if value is NOT empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html, which is part of a webform:

`<input type="hidden" name="userID" id="control_COLUMN43" value="%%userID%%">`

The value of this field is dynamically generated by a database. It's possible that the value of this field is empty.

Next to this, I created a function which sends the value of this field (via Ajax) to another database, upon a submit of the webform.

What I want to do now is: only execute this function if the value of the field "userID" is NOT empty. If it's empty, I don't want this function to be executed.

So I assume it will be something like this, but I'm struggling to find the correct way to do this:

```
if (#control_COLUMN43 !=== "") //this is the id of the field
{
function SendAjax()
   {
      if
      {
        //code
      }
      else
      {
        //code
      }
    }
}
else
{
//don't execute function
}
```

Or the other way around I guess?

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @cp1 is right and solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
    // Also u can add null check
        if(data !== '') {
   // do something
}
```

If, however you just want to make sure, that a code will run only for "reasonable" values, then you can, as others have stated already, write:

```
if (data) {
  // do something
}
```

Since, in javascript, both null values, and empty strings, equals to false (i.e. null == false).

The difference between those 2 parts of code is that, for the first one, every value that is not specifically an empty string, will enter the if. But, on the second one, every true-ish value will enter the if: false, 0, null, undefined and empty strings, would not.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check empty value like this





    function isEmpty(str) {
         return (!str || 0 === str.length);
    }

    var val = document.getElementById('control_COLUMN43').value;
    var col = isEmpty(val);
    if (col) {
     function SendAjax(){
      if
      {
        //code
      }
      else
      {
        //code
      }
    }
}
else
{
//don't execute function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the contents of the form element
var control_COLUMN43 = document.getElementById("control_COLUMN43").value;

// process the data
if( control_COLUMN43 != "" ) {......
```

Comment: @Luca I would've thought that the comments within the provided code would be sufficient to let the OP "know" what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues at once:

- You are mixing up **declaring** a function with **calling** it.
- To get the value from a control, use `document.getElementById("...").value`
- The proper notation for `not ===` is `!==`.

This is how it goes:

```
// Declare the function
function SendAjax()
{
    if
    {
        //code
    }
    else
    {
        //code
    }
}

// Get value
var value = document.getElementById("control_COLUMN43").value;

// Call the function conditionally
if (value !== "")
{
    SendAjax();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare functions inside the conditions. If you do then at the time of execution if the condition is not met, function will not be available which may lead to errors. Hence, you should place the condition inside the function.

You can modify your condition to following

```
function SendAjax() {
    if (document.getEelementById("control_COLUMN43").value) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the input by using getElementById(id).value
and declare your function outside the if block like:

```
function SendAjax()
   {
      if
      {
        //code
      }
      else
      {
        //code
      }
    }

if (document.getElementById('txt_name').value) //this is the id of the field
{
  SendAjax()
}
else
{
//don't execute function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement you need, without JQuery, should be like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("control_COLUMN43").value !=== "") {
   // .. commands
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to check `value` property of the `input` element. Using dom selectors first you can select a element using id then you can access `value` attribute for element. If it's not null or undefined or just empty spaces then you can call your function

```js
function handleClick(){
  // Extract value from input element
  let val = document.getElementById('input').value;
  // Check value is empty or not
  if(val){
    // If not empty
    console.log('Value is : ' + val);
  }
  else{
    // If empty
    console.log('Empty input');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button onclick="handleClick()">SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your hidden input value using `document.getElementById()` and then check if it is null like following:

```
var userId = document.getElementById("control_COLUMN43");
if (userId) //this is the id of the field
{
   SendAjax()
}
else
{
  alert("UserId is null);
}

function SendAjax()
   {
      if
      {
        //code
      }
      else
      {
        //code
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you write in if condition is not correct ID value must be get like:

```
if(document.getElementById("control_COLUMN43").value != ''){
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in the question.

Comment: Is your problem solve using this?

Comment: oh sorry I forget to see tag of javascript

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it later this afternoon!

Comment: @CP1 Seems to work! How do I state my "else" part? If I put "return false" I get an error "illegal return" statement, if I remove the else I get: "sendAjax is not a function". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In if condition check $("#control_COLUMN43").val()
It can be null or '' so you can apply condition accordingly.